# Using Bool In Struct in SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I have a problem when trying to use a bool as part of a swift struct.

```
struct MapPrefs: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isShown: Bool

}
```

An array of these prefs are provided by a store to a swift-UI view

```
class MapPrefsStore : ObservableObject {

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    @Published var MapPrefs: [MapPrefs] {
        didSet { willChange.send(()) }
    }

    init(mapPrefs: [MapPrefs]) {
        self.MapPrefs = mapPrefs
    }

}
```

The Settings View Observes the Store and passes the array to a cell view

```
struct SettingsView: View {


    @ObservedObject var mapPrefsStore = MapPrefsStore(mapPrefs: MapPrefsTestData)


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List {

                 Section(header: Text("Map Preferences"), footer: Text("")) {

                    ForEach(mapPrefsStore.MapPrefs) { mapPrefs in
                        MapPrefsCell(mapPrefs: mapPrefs)
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: moveMap)
                                }
                .background(Color.clear)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
    func moveMap(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        guard let sourceIndex = Array(source).first else { return }
        mapPrefsStore.MapPrefs.insert(mapPrefsStore.MapPrefs.remove(at: sourceIndex), at: destination)
    }
}

struct MapPrefsCell : View {
    let mapPrefs: MapPrefs

    var body: some View {

        Toggle(isOn: mapPrefs.isShown) {
            Text(mapPrefs.name)
        }
    }
}
}
```

this gives me the following error

`Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'`

I can't figure out how to allow the called function (MapPrefsCell) the ability to access the isShown property.  I tried various combinations of adding the $ sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer above works partially but because I am sharing those settings with other views I needed to be able to read and write on the toggle change so I converted the struct into a class

Here is what I did so that others can benefit.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class MapPrefs: Identifiable, ObservableObject {

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var id = UUID()
    @Published var name: String = "" {didSet { willChange.send(()) }}
    @Published var isShown: Bool = false  {didSet { willChange.send(()) }}

    init (name: String , isShown: Bool) {
        //self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.isShown = isShown
    }
}
```

Then in the creation of the view I can access the property and the toggle works

```
struct MapPrefsCell : View {
    @ObservedObject var mapPrefs: MapPrefs

    var body: some View {

        Toggle(isOn: $mapPrefs.isShown ) {
            Text(mapPrefs.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isShown is declared as Bool. Passing it with `$` won't work as you can not convert it to `Binding<Bool>`.

You could declare it as `@State` in your struct:

```
struct MapPrefs: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    @State var isShown: Bool

}
```

and then pass it as Binding...

```
Toggle(isOn: mapPrefs.$isShown) {
    Text(mapPrefs.name)
}
```

**Edit:**

You can also create a custom State and use the value of your mapPrefs for that State. But then you will need to store changes to your object afterwards. In this case you do not need to declare it as @State

```
struct MapPrefs: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var isShown: Bool

}

struct MapPrefsCell : View {
    let mapPrefs: MapPrefs

    @State var toggle : Bool

    init(mapPrefs: MapPrefs)
    {
        //create State with initial value here 
        self._toggle = State(initialValue: self.mapPrefs.isShown)
    }

    var body: some View {

        Toggle(isOn: $toggle) {
            Text(mapPrefs.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: It works just need to save the state as it seems to switch back on straight after I change it

Comment: It no longer shows the error but the toggle won't' stay changed is it because of the" let  mapPrefs" in MapPrefCell, should that be a var instead ??

Comment: You can also use @State and then set the initial value from your mapPrefs. Then you won't need to declare toggle as State. However, you will need to store changes to your object at the end. You can do this with a custom Binding and set your values.